# centos - plesk - apache file owner

Tags: centos, plesk, mkdir, centos6

I have a question.

Server: VPS
System: Centos 6 + Plesk 11

save_mode = off;

Problem:

I have a script that creates folders for users.
mkdir('/var/www/vhosts/website.com/private/'.$user_id.', 0755, true);

And true the Plesk API i create a ftp user for the new folder.

The problem is that my php script create the new whit the following group and user:  apache(502)/503

The ftp users has no rights in this folder at all.

If i create folders true ftp the group and user are: 505/10000

Answer (score 3):

It is because your PHP script is running in `mod_php` mode and executes under `Apache` user. The easiest solution would be to switch your site to run in `FastCGI` mode, so that PHP script is running under your PHP user and there is no ownership conflict.

Comment: My PHP is already running as FastCGI mode, but it still get 505 permission error. :(

Comment: Googling about, lots of people report memory leak problems and other slowness after switching to FastCGI. Just beware.

Answer (score 1):

The question is pretty old, but I found a solution so thought it might be helpful for someone.
Following commands needs to be executed using root access.

```
cd /var/www/vhosts/yourdomain.com
chown -R youruser:psacln httpdocs
chmod -R g+w httpdocs/wp-content
find httpdocs -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
```

For details explanation you can view the link
http://www.ryanbelanger.com/wordpress-file-permissions/